# creating a cell array within a cell array using cellfun

Tags: matlab, cell

If I create a cell array using:

```
clear all
data = {rand(1,5),rand(1,4),rand(1,4),rand(1,6)};
a = cell(1,length(data));
```

how is it then possible to create a cell array in each cell of a which is the same length as the corresponding cell in data. I know this can easily be done using a loop, but how would it be possible by using the cellfun function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like that?

```
data = {rand(1,5),rand(1,4),rand(1,4),rand(1,6)};
a2=cellfun(@(x) cell(size(x)),data,'UniformOutput',0)
a2 = 
    {1x5 cell}    {1x4 cell}    {1x4 cell}    {1x6 cell}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this by using [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) to just get the sizes of each cell, create all the cells you need, then divide them up using [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
>> cellSizes = cellfun('size',data,2);
>> a = mat2cell(cell(1,sum(cellSizes)),1,cellSizes)

a = 

    {1x5 cell}    {1x4 cell}    {1x4 cell}    {1x6 cell}
```